# Do/did former Soviet republic leaders generally attend the May Victory Day parade in Moscow?

Tags: russian-federation, international, soviet-union, symbols

It's been noted in a [2017 article](https://balkaninsight.com/2017/06/06/moldovan-president-ridiculed-after-putin-joke-06-05-2017/) that that year only Moldovan president Dodon attended the May Victory Day parade in Moscow:

> Dodon was also the only head of state from the former Soviet republics in the Commonwealth of Independent States who stood at Putin’s side for the May 9 Victory Day Parade, marking the end of World War II.

Is this unusual though? I found from a [2015 article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/apr/15/moscow-defiant-victory-day-parade-european-kim-jong-un-9-may-russia-ukraine) that said that Western leaders sometimes attended in the past but were snubbing the parade that year (although Merkel visited the next day, in a lower-profile event.)

However, I could not find whether the 2017 occurrence of only the Moldovan president attending *from among the leaders of former Soviet republics* is actually unusual. Did e.g. pre-2014 parades see more of these former Soviet republics leaders attending the parade?

Comment: Wikipedia actually has articles for the Victory Parades in Moscow for many individual years: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Moscow_Victory_Parade, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шаблон:Парад_Победы. That might be a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, things have changed after the annexation of Crimea, as explained in this article by [Deutsche Welle](https://www.dw.com/ru/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B/a-48541167) (via Google Translate):

> Moscow does not expect the heads of foreign states to take part in the
> celebrations marking Victory Day on May 9, 2019. This was reported on
> Monday, April 29, by the Kremlin press service to the RIA Novosti news
> agency.
>
> "No," - said the press secretary of Russian President Vladimir Putin -
> Dmitry Peskov, answering the agency's question about whether foreign
> leaders are expected to arrive in Russia on May 9. Earlier, he stated
> that the Kremlin did not specifically invite any of the foreign
> leaders to celebrate Victory Day.
>
> **The number of foreign guests at the Victory Parade fell sharply after the annexation of Crimea by Russia**. Since Russia's annexation
> of the Ukrainian peninsula of Crimea in 2014, the number of heads of
> state attending the Victory Parade in Moscow has dropped markedly. If
> 30 foreign leaders were present at the celebration of the 70th
> anniversary of Victory Day on May 9, 2015 on Red Square, then in 2016
> only the President of Kazakhstan Nursultan Nazarbayev arrived in
> Moscow.
>
> In 2017, only Moldovan President Igor Dodon visited Russia on Victory
> Day. In 2018, Serbian President Aleksandar Vucic and Israeli Prime
> Minister Benjamin Netanyahu attended the May 9 celebrations.

The list of attendees to the 2015 parade [roughly reflects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Moscow_Victory_Day_Parade) the list of nations [recognizing Crimea as part of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_problem#Pro-Russian_stances_on_Crimea) or [taking a neutral side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_problem#Other_positions). The 2005 parade [had a much more diverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_Moscow_Victory_Day_Parade) list of guests, showcasing the dwindling of Russia's international reputation.

Comment: Still the number of representatives from the former Soviet republics (what I'm asking about) seems relatively constant. True, in 2005 both Nazarbayev and Niyazov (Turkmenistan) came, but it seems it was 1-2 of these at the most. My guess is that these CIS country leaders cannot really afford to snub Putin, but that he also won't like invite just everyone from CIS at the same time.

Comment: Actually, in the full 2005 list (which is collapsed on Wikipedia, unlike the lead photo), there were also Voronin (Moldova), Bakiyev (Kyrgyzstan), Aliyev (Azerbaijan), and Rahmon (Tajikistan),  and Karimov (Uzbekistan). So that's more like 7 then. But I'm not sure these all stood next to Putin at the parade.

Comment: @Fizz in [this photo](https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/celebrations-of-the-60th-anniversary-of-the-allied-victory-over-nazi-picture-id111013023?s=2048x2048) you can see Aliyev, Rahmon and Nazarbayev. Possibly others too, the resolution is too low. Bakiyev is seen [here](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/russian-federation-russian-first-lady-ludmila-russian-news-photo/52777656). Another crop is [here](https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/russian-federation-nearly-60-heads-of-state-and-government-and-other-picture-id52777805?s=2048x2048).

Comment: @Fizz Karimov attended a veterans event [on May 8th](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/russian-federation-kyrgyz-interim-president-kurmanbek-news-photo/52775546) along with Yuschenko (Ukraine). The Ukrainian President apparently chose to attend a [parade in Kiev](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/president-of-ukraine-viktor-yushchenko-waves-as-he-marches-news-photo/52778650) the next day.